# Grails,Gorm, using createCriteria or some other alternative

Tags: grails, grails-orm

For example, I've parent class Author:

```
class Author {    
    String name
    static hasMany = [
         fiction: Book, 
         nonFiction: Book
    ]
}
```

and a child class Book:

```
class Book {    
    String title
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
}
```

I've done some records to Author using:

```
def fictBook = new Book(title: "IT")
def nonFictBook = new Book(title: "On Writing: A Memoir of the Craft")
def a = new Author(name: "Stephen King")
             .addToFiction(fictBook)
             .addToNonFiction(nonFictBook)
             .save()
```

How can I found child-class record by parent and parent-class record by child?

I tried to use findBy method, as below:

```
def book = Book.get(1)
def author = Author.findByFiction(book)
```

But I get an error:

```
Parameter "#2" is not set; SQL statement:
```

I read, what in some relationship findBy is denied for using, how I can rewrite it using criteria or some others methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add this `belongsTo`

```
static belongsTo = [author: Author]
```

this triggers the addition of a property named `author` of type `Author` (by an AST transform during compilation), effectively like declaring

```
Author author
```

but don't do that, it'd be redundant.

So if you have a book, it's `Author` is accessible via that property:

```
def book = Book.get(1)
def author = book.author
```

Comment: Thanks. Myself guessed about it second before I read your post)